# Is there any option in tally that should be changed for altering stock item names using xml request?

Tags: xml, vb.net, tally

This is my xml request

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<IMPORTDATA>
<REQUESTDESC>
<REPORTNAME>All Masters</REPORTNAME>
</REQUESTDESC>
<REQUESTDATA>
<TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
<STOCKITEM NAME="0000" ACTION="alter">
<NAME.LIST>
<NAME>newname</NAME>
</NAME.LIST>
<ADDITIONALNAME.LIST>
<ADDITIONALNAME>0000</ADDITIONALNAME>
</ADDITIONALNAME.LIST>
</STOCKITEM>
</TALLYMESSAGE>
</REQUESTDATA>
</IMPORTDATA>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Response from tally

```
<RESPONSE>
    <CREATED>0</CREATED>
    <ALTERED>0</ALTERED>
    <DELETED>0</DELETED>
    <LASTVCHID>0</LASTVCHID>
    <LASTMID>0</LASTMID>
    <COMBINED>0</COMBINED>
    <IGNORED>1</IGNORED>
    <ERRORS>0</ERRORS>
    <CANCELLED>0</CANCELLED>
</RESPONSE>
```

First it's working, could create, alter any stock items, but then alter is not working.

Would like to know how to edit (alter) stock item name in tally using a XML request

Comment: Xml is just data.  Could you update your question with the code to process and manipulate this data.  Where does this xml come from and where does it go?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send same XML twice it won't work

as when you send First time, stock item name "0000" is altered to "newname"

If you want to alter same stock item again then you need use "newname" in attribute

```
<STOCKITEM NAME="newname" ACTION="alter">
```